# Display posts on a custom page from only a specific category?

Tags: posts, categories, query-posts, archives

I'm trying to get my news page to display content from one category only (number 3) but I cant seem to get it to work. Instead of just displaying posts from category 3 it displays posts from all category's.

Here is my code:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

            <div class="content news_page">

                       <h1>Latest News</h1>     

                       <?php $args = array(
                            'post_type' => 'post' ,
                            'orderby' => 'date' ,
                            'order' => 'DESC' ,
                            'posts_per_page' => 6,
                            'category'         => '3',
                            'paged' => get_query_var('paged'),
                            'post_parent' => $parent
                       ); ?>
                       <?php query_posts($args); ?>




                       <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
                            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                                <div class="large-4 medium-4 small-12 columns">
                                    <div class="latest_news_cont">
                                    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>

                                    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><h5><?php the_title(); ?></h5></a>
                                    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                                    <p style="text-align:center;"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="readmore_news">Read more</a></p>
<br>
<div class="clear"></div>
                                       </div>
                                    </div>

                            <?php endwhile; ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>


<div class="clear"></div>

            </div><!--end of content-->



<div class="clear"></div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: _Exactly_ what doesn't work? Also, please do not us `query_posts`.

Comment: Hi, instead of displaying posts from a certain category it displays posts from all categorys

Comment: Is your news page your posts page set in your Reading Settings?

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/290909/133699

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The argument isn't `category`, it is `cat`.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters) Your query fails because you are using an argument that doesn't exist.

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'post' ,
  'orderby' => 'date' ,
  'order' => 'DESC' ,
  'posts_per_page' => 6,
  'cat'         => '3',
  'paged' => get_query_var('paged'),
  'post_parent' => $parent
); 
$q = new WP_Query($args);
if ( $q->have_posts() ) { 
  while ( $q->have_posts() ) {
    $q->the_post();
    // your loop
  }
}
```

Notice that I have converted your `query_posts()` into a new `WP_Query` object. Do not use `query_posts()`, ever. Even the Codex states so.

> > Note: This function isn't meant to be used by plugins or themes. As
> >     explained later, there are better, more performant options to alter
> >     the main query. query_posts() is overly simplistic and problematic way
> >     to modify main query of a page by replacing it with new instance of
> >     the query. It is inefficient (re-runs SQL queries) and will outright
> >     fail in some circumstances (especially often when dealing with posts
> >     pagination). Any modern WP code should use more reliable methods, like
> >     making use of pre_get_posts hook, for this purpose.
>
> http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts

Also note that I removed unnecessary PHP opening and closing tags and formatted the code for better readability. That [alternative control structure syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) is a formula for failure, in my experience.

Answer (score 7):

Get First Five Posts With Specific Category

```
<?php
        // the query
        $the_query = new WP_Query(array(
            'category_name' => 'post_category_name',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page' => 5,
        ));
        ?>

        <?php if ($the_query->have_posts()) : ?>
            <?php while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
                <?php the_category(); ?>
                <?php the_title(); ?>
                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                <?php the_content(); ?>

            <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

        <?php else : ?>
            <p><?php __('No News'); ?></p>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would personally do this rather.

Instead of:

```
'category' => '3',
```

Replace it with this:

```
'category_name' => 'my-category-slug'
```

Obviously find the name of your category slug and replace 'my-category-slug'.

As mentioned by @s-ha-dum it would be better to not use this method and rather use WP_Query method. You can see it in the WordPress Codex here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Parameters

Comment: Thanks. This gave me the solution to know that in "category_name" property you need to send the "slug" instead the name of the category (including spaces) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in your functions file:

```
function wpsites_display_one_category( $query ) {
if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
    $query->set( 'cat', '3' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpsites_display_one_category' );
```

Change the is_home() [conditional tag](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) to match your news page or posts page loop if needed. Whatever you set in Settings > Reading.

Answer (score 0):

You should change

```
'category'         => '3',
```

to in your code.

```
'cat' => '3',
```